Existence of a sequence of real numbers
Let
$$g_{c;k}(z):=\frac{2 (c-z-1)^{k+2}}{(k+1) (k+2)}+\frac{1}{2} (-c+z+2)^2 z^k+\frac{-2 c (k+2)+4 k+6}{(k+1) (k+2)}+\frac{2z}{k+1}.$$
Do there exist $c\in(1,3/2)$ and a sequence $(a_k)_{k=0}^\infty$ of real numbers such that
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k g_{c;k}(z)=1\quad\text{and}\quad \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k\ge0$$
for all $z\in(0,1)$?
